# Why doesn't noise display album arts embedded in mp3 files?

Tags: music, audio

I have elementary os freya installed, and noise audio player doesn't display the art embedded in the mp3 files, it shows the music data in the id3 tag but not the picture, what's up?

Comment: Could you try to play a song? Is the picture shown afterwards? Then this is the following bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/noise/+bug/1215558

Comment: no, the picture doesn't showup after playing either.